# How do Shias perform Salat behind Sunni Imam?

Tags: salat, sunni, shiism

Aoa,

In my office there is majority of Sunni brothers and I perform salat behind Sunni Imam, and also during Jumaah prayers in nearby sunni mosque, but I wonder whether I am doing in the correct way? Like Skipping Qunoot. So I want to know what things should we skip/change while performing with sunni brothers.

And what about Salam? Can we do it in Sunni way?

P.S: I am not asking about whether it is allowed to pray behind sunni imam. So no discussions about it.

I do taqleed of Ayatollah Sistani.

Wasalam,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably would have to do it as a 'taba2iya' (fellowship) prayer and not full jamaa2a prayer.  In the taba2iya prayer you will be following the Imam in all the acts he does (sujoud, roukou2, etc) however will still have to be recieting everything on your own.

So from the outside one would think you are doing jamaa2 with them but in actuality you are doing the prayer alone but participating in the same actions as the group.

With regards to Qunoot you can either do a quick one just before going to roukou or I think it might be ok to skip it as its not required.

The Salam part is not required, so you would have to set in your intention that your prayer is done before turning your head to do their salam (and then you can just do their salam) but its not apart of your salat.

Comment: I was confused about the salam part, thanks for quick reply. Now I'm more confident praying behind sunni imam. Jazakallah